# How to return filtered array in angular and export that to jspdf

Tags: angular

I have an array in my angular like this

```
<div class="row tabel content" id="contentdata" 
    *ngFor="let d of ((data 
        | filter: {id:searchText,nama: searchText, jenis_kelamin:searchText,  komentar: searchText})) 
        | paginate: {itemsPerPage: 4, currentPage: p}
    ;">


        <div class="cell" data-title="No">
            {{d.id}}
        </div>
        <div class="cell" data-title="Nama">
            {{d.nama}}
        </div>
        <div class="cell" data-title="Jenis_kelamin">
            {{d.jenis_kelamin}}
        </div>
        <div class="cell" data-title="Komentar">
            {{d.komentar}}
        </div>
        <div class="cell" data-title="Action">
            <button type="button" (click)="Delete(d)" class="btn res btn-danger mr-2">Hapus</button>
            <button type="button" (click)="Edit(d)" class="btn res btn-warning">Edit</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-primary"  (click)="exportPDF()" target="_blank" >
        export pdf
    </button>
```

and when I press the button I want to export that filtered data use jspdf, there's the code when I press the button

```
exportPDF(){
let doc = new jsPDF();

const header = [['No', 'Nama', 'Jenis Kelamin', 'Komentar']];
const rows=[];
const data = this.data;

data.forEach(elm => {
  const temp = [elm.id, elm.nama, elm.jenis_kelamin, elm.komentar];
  rows.push(temp);
  console.log('Rows', rows); // showing all data
});

doc.autoTable({
  head: header,
  body: rows,
});
doc.save('demo.pdf');}
```

I want it when I press export button it will export the filtered data to pdf, anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`Array.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) function:

```
rows = data.filter(elm => {
  // Here you should write your filter logic either returning
  // true - if the element should be kept
  // false - if the element should be filtered out

  // Example:
  return elm.id === 3
})

doc.autoTable({
  head: header,
  body: rows,
});
```